# Broken Interfaces and wpa_supplicant

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, internet

I have some how broken the network interface configuration on my pi 3 B running Jessie.

Is there a way to restore all network configurations to default, or a repository where I can copy the original files from?

I am unable to do a fresh install as I have a lot of other configuration already done.

Wireless tab on desktop shows:

```
No Wireless interfaces found
```

The problem occurred after attempting this tutorial:

https://howchoo.com/g/ndy1zte2yjn/how-to-set-up-wifi-on-your-raspberry-pi-without-ethernet

Answer (score 1):

[How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
has instructions to set up, and also contains listings of the default files, for both Jessie and Stretch.

There is no "default" `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, this is created. There are brief instructions on how to set it up, and links to Foundation tutorials.

`No Wireless interfaces found` can mean there is an actual hardware problem, or it can be due to `dhcpcd` being disabled (often due to changes to `/etc/network/interfaces`).